# Dynamically changing position of gridview in windows phone

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-phone-8

I have created a WP8 application in grid view. It shows users images in grid view[basically thumbnail of the image]. And it works perfectly. But I want to update the application, where in a user can click on image thumbnail and can change the position from last row, last column to first row, first column. Is there any way to achieve the same ?

Comment: you can use reposition of elements in gridview if you are looking to repositio them ??

Comment: can you please be bit more elaborate ? My scenario is " user will click and hold a thumbnail present in the gird. Then he will reposition that item wherever he wants in that page". Is this can be achieved in WP8 ??

Answer (score 0):

there is no direct option but you can use third party controls such as :

Orderable List from Bewise phone controls toolkit.
DataBoundListBox from Telerik RadControls for Windows Phone also supports items reordering.